# How to direct user after comment save

Tags: comments, hooks, actions, troubleshooting

I've been trying to direct the user to the specific page after they posted the comment, but that not luck for me.

Here is the my code blocks

My first try:

```
add_action('wp_insert_comment', array($this, 'redirectAfterCommented'));

public function redirectAfterCommented() {

   //some bussines logics

   wp_redirect('http://example.com/sample-jpage');

}
```

Also, I've try with another with the following code

```
add_action('comment_post', array($this, 'redirectAfterCommented '), 10, 2);

public function redirectAfterCommented () {

   // some business logic

   wp_redirect('https://example.com/sample-page');

}
```

Do hooked in the wrong place? if so, where should I hook to redirect the commentator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the filter `comment_post_redirect`:

```
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'comment_redirect' );

function comment_redirect( $location ) {
    $location = 'http://example.com/sample-page';
    // or:
    // $location = get_page_link( page_ID );
    // $location = get_page_link( get_page_by_path( 'sample-page' )->ID )
    return $location;
}
```